# speed up complex query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am trying to make this query faster

```
SELECT
    contacts_cstm.case_id_c AS 'Case_id',
CONCAT(cont.first_name, ' ',cont.last_name) AS 'Contact Name',
contacts_cstm.id_c AS 'Id',
'Contacts' AS 'Module',
reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c as '% Paid'
[... more cols in select ...]
FROM
contacts cont
INNER JOIN contacts_cstm on contacts_cstm.id_c = cont.id and cont.deleted=0
INNER JOIN leads on leads.contact_id = cont.id AND leads.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c ON leads.id = leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1leads_ida AND leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN aggre_aggregatevalues_cstm ON leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1aggre_aggregatevalues_idb = aggre_aggregatevalues_cstm.id_c 
Left JOIN contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c on contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.contacts_ccs_ccs_1contacts_ida = cont.id AND contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.deleted = 0
Left JOIN ccs_ccs on ccs_ccs.id = contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.contacts_ccs_ccs_1ccs_ccs_idb AND ccs_ccs.deleted = 0
LEFT JOIN ccs_ccs_cstm on ccs_ccs_cstm.id_c = ccs_ccs.id
LEFT JOIN users advocate on advocate.id = contacts_cstm.user_id1_c
LEFT JOIN users practitioner on practitioner.id = contacts_cstm.user_id2_c
LEFT JOIN contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c on contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1contacts_ida = cont.id 
LEFT JOIN reso_tax_preparation_cstm on  reso_tax_preparation_cstm.id_c = contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1reso_tax_preparation_idb AND contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.deleted=0
 
WHERE
(DATEDIFF(NOW(),contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) >= 14)  
                   
AND (reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c != '100.00' OR (reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c = '100.00' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) < 120) )
```

I tried following things

using Explain to see details
table contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c used 113470 rows .

this is the explained output

[image]

so these condition

```
AND (reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c != '100.00' OR (reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c = '100.00' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) < 120) )
```

taking time

2. moved deleted=0 condition from where condition to join condition
3. Applied limit 1 to exist queries
4. innodb to related tables
5. applied  indexed to following columns by these command

   ALTER TABLE `reso_tax_preparation_cstm` ADD INDEX(`percentage_paid_c`);
   ALTER TABLE `contacts_cstm` ADD INDEX( `ctax_status_update_date_c`, `last_contact_date_c`, `resolution_type_c`, `resolution_service_level_c`, `misc_reso_service_level_c`, `tax_prep_missing_info_c`);
   ALTER TABLE `contacts_cstm` ADD INDEX(`user_id2_c`);
   ALTER TABLE `reso_tax_preparation_cstm` ADD INDEX(`service_status_c`);
   ALTER TABLE `reso_ancillary_services_cstm` ADD INDEX(`service_status_c`);
   ALTER TABLE `contacts_cstm` ADD INDEX(`missing_info_final_deadline_c`);
6. trying to split these queries into unions ,but count changes.

query still takes 9 seconds

6. converted left joins to subqueries

   ```
   SELECT
    contacts_cstm.case_id_c AS 'Case_id',
     CONCAT( cont.first_name, ' ', cont.last_name ) AS 'Contact Name',
     contacts_cstm.id_c AS 'Id',
     'Contacts' AS 'Module',
      (select percentage_paid_c  AS '% Paid' from  
       contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c 
     LEFT JOIN
       reso_tax_preparation_cstm 
       ON reso_tax_preparation_cstm.id_c = contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1reso_tax_preparation_idb 
      AND contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.deleted = 0 

       where 
       contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c.contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1contacts_ida = cont.id 
      AND
      ( 
          reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c != '100.00' 
      OR
      (
         reso_tax_preparation_cstm.percentage_paid_c = '100.00' 
         AND DATEDIFF( NOW(), contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) < 120 
      )
   )
     limit 1
     ),

   DATEDIFF(NOW(), contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) AS 'Days since Last Contact',
   (
      SELECT
         COUNT(reqcl_requiredclientinfo.id) 
      FROM
         contacts 
         INNER JOIN
            contacts_cstm 
            ON contacts_cstm.id_c = contacts.id 
         LEFT JOIN
            contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1_c 
            ON contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1_c.contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1contacts_ida = contacts.id 
         LEFT JOIN
            reqcl_requiredclientinfo 
            ON reqcl_requiredclientinfo.id = contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1_c.contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1reqcl_requiredclientinfo_idb 
            AND reqcl_requiredclientinfo.deleted = 0 
         LEFT JOIN
            reqcl_requiredclientinfo_cstm 
            ON reqcl_requiredclientinfo_cstm.id_c = reqcl_requiredclientinfo.id 
      WHERE
         contacts.id = cont.id 
   )
   AS 'Number of Required Info Records',
   contacts_cstm.resolution_type_c AS 'Resolution Type',
   CONCAT( advocate.first_name, ' ', advocate.last_name ) AS 'Current Case Advocate',
   CONCAT( practitioner.first_name, ' ', advocate.last_name ) AS 'Current Practitioner',
   DATEDIFF( NOW(), contacts_cstm.ctax_status_update_date_c) AS 'Days in active Ctax Status ',
   contacts_cstm.resolution_service_level_c AS 'Resolution Service Level',
   contacts_cstm.tax_preparation_level_c AS 'Tax Prep Service Level',
   contacts_cstm.misc_reso_service_level_c AS 'Misc Res Service Level',
   ccs_ccs_cstm.ccs_status_c AS `CCS Status` 
   FROM
     contacts cont 
    INNER JOIN
      contacts_cstm 
      ON contacts_cstm.id_c = cont.id 
   INNER JOIN
      leads 
      ON leads.contact_id = cont.id 
   LEFT JOIN
      leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c 
      ON leads.id = leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1leads_ida 
      AND leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.deleted = 0 
   LEFT JOIN
      aggre_aggregatevalues_cstm 
      ON leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c.leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1aggre_aggregatevalues_idb = aggre_aggregatevalues_cstm.id_c 
   LEFT JOIN
      contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c 
      ON contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.contacts_ccs_ccs_1contacts_ida = cont.id 
      AND contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.deleted = 0 
   LEFT JOIN
      ccs_ccs 
      ON ccs_ccs.id = contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c.contacts_ccs_ccs_1ccs_ccs_idb 
      AND ccs_ccs.deleted = 0 
   LEFT JOIN
      ccs_ccs_cstm 
      ON ccs_ccs_cstm.id_c = ccs_ccs.id 
   LEFT JOIN
      users advocate 
      ON advocate.id = contacts_cstm.user_id1_c 
   LEFT JOIN
      users practitioner 
      ON practitioner.id = contacts_cstm.user_id2_c
   ```

this reduces time and count , but i wanted to be sure this is right

what more can i try

Comment: Please include the explain output in the question!

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid un-sargable constructs:

  ```
  AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(),contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c) < 120)
  ```

-->

```
  AND  contacts_cstm.last_contact_date_c > NOW() - INTERVAL 120 DAY
```

- `OR` is hard to Optimize.  If you can't get rid of it, we can talk about using `UNION`.
- Remove any Joins that do not actually participate in the query.
- Single-column indexes are sometimes not as good as 'composite' (multi-column) indexes.
- Some of these indexes may help with the original query andor with the 'subquery' reformulation:

  ```
  aggre_aggregatevalues_cstm:  INDEX(id_c)
  ccs_ccs_cstm:  INDEX(id_c,  ccs_status_c)
  contacts_cstm:  INDEX(id_c)
  contacts_cstm:  INDEX(last_contact_date_c, id_c,  case_id_c, user_id1_c, user_id2_c)
  contacts_ccs_ccs_1_c:  INDEX(contacts_ccs_ccs_1contacts_ida,  deleted, contacts_ccs_ccs_1ccs_ccs_idb)
  contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1_c:  INDEX(contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1contacts_ida,  contacts_reso_tax_preparation_1reso_tax_preparation_idb, deleted)
  contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1_c:  INDEX(contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1contacts_ida,  contacts_reqcl_requiredclientinfo_1reqcl_requiredclientinfo_idb)
  leads:  INDEX(contact_id,  deleted, id)
  leads:  INDEX(contact_id,  id)
  leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1_c:  INDEX(leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1leads_ida,  deleted, leads_aggre_aggregatevalues_1aggre_aggregatevalues_idb)
  reso_tax_preparation_cstm:  INDEX(percentage_paid_c, id_c)
  reqcl_requiredclientinfo_cstm:  INDEX(id_c)
  ```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.